# Visual Studio Online build step PackageLocation being ignored

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, azure-pipelines

I have a Visual Studio Online build definition that seems to be misbehaving, but I'm not sure if I've just misconfigured something.

There is a build step which is configured as follows:

**Type:** Visual Studio Build

**Solution:** **\mysolutionfile.sln

**MSBuild Arguments:** `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"`

The build runs successfully, and the build log shows the msbuild command is executed as follows:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\a\1\s\Code\mysolutionfile.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,(more removed for brevity) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="C:\a\1\a" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_6efdabeb-1c75-43a7-96b2-f40e19a68a35_build_14_122"`

As you can see, the package location is correctly set: `/p:PackageLocation="C:\a\1\a"`

However, later in the build log, the package step shows this log entry:

`2017-01-20T05:07:30.9771422Z   Executing command ["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:manifest='C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\mysolution55\SourceManifest.xml' -dest:package='C:\a\1\s\Code\mysolutionfile\bin\Release\MSDeployPackage\mysolutionfile.zip' -verb:sync -replace:match='C:\\Users\\buildguest\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\PublishTemp\\mysolutionfile55\\',replace='website\' -retryAttempts:20 -disablerule:BackupRule]`

As you can see, in this case the package is being sent to `-dest:package='C:\a\1\s\Code\mysolutionfile\bin\Release\MSDeployPackage\mysolutionfile.zip'` - and this is indeed where the zip file ends up.

As far as I can tell, this looks wrong. I want to have the packaged application binaries and files end up in the staging directory, but msbuild is overriding me somewhere and putting them into the source checkout folder.

In case it's relevant, the solution contains two projects: an ASP.NET Core web app that is targeting the full .NET Framework; and a portable class library.

Am I doing something wrong in the build configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your issue in my TFS Environment and I got the same result with. The package under the "C:\a\1\s" folder not "C:\a\1\a'.

As a workaround, you could add a **Copy files** step to copy the package from the source folder to $(build.stagingDirectory) path.

Comment: Thanks - the workaround works. However does this look like it's a bug? If so, where should I report it? I'm not sure if the problem is with MSBuild or the way VSO is running the build.

Comment: @John The feedback link is:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx . You could report here.

Comment: Thanks. MS Connect pushed me off to another site to file the bug. If anyone is interested in following this, it's filed at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/12933/visual-studio-online-build-step-packagelocation-be.html

Comment: Another update - this has been confirmed as a bug in ASP.NET Core and is being tracked here now: https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/106

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it did not work as you expected because the variable name should be `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` instead of `build.stagingDirectory`

Example:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    #msbuildArgs: '/T:"MyProject1" /p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /nowarn:FS0049'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: MyWebSiteArtefactZIP
```

**There is also another way to Deploy:**

If you have created a Publish Profile (you can use Visual Studio for that),
it is also possible to Publish directly from **MSBuild**, you can put the Web App username/password in the Azure DevOps Pipeline variables and use them:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:Configuration=Release /P:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PublishProfile="MyPublishProfile.pubxml" /P:Username=$(username);Password=$(password)'
```

Comment: How does /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"' works? If I tried it locally an error shows up like "must be a file and not a directory".
But "ArtifactStagingDirectory" ist always an directory?!

Comment: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) is a variable that Azure DevOps creates. It contains a Directory Path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services

Comment: thanks for your response.
But this will not answer my question:
How or why does it work to use "just a path of a directory" at "PackageLocation" in AzureDevOps even MSBuild locally shows up it must be a filepath (not a directory)?
Because of some environment variables?